# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies to type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection'

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

May be my question is simple or i am new to this ,the thing is While trying to do the below code in the item data bound of a repeater im gettin  the error Unable to cast object of type
 *System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.AutoPublishLog_06BC2AA20C3D11E56D78DD544C2C7E5211D828344650C93B9AA23BDEE16A6DCE' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView''.*

Error Line is

```
Dim row As System.Data.DataRowView = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem,   System.Data.DataRowView)
```

Any help ,Thanks in advance

code snippet

```
Protected Sub AutoPublishList_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles AutoPublishList.ItemDataBound

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then
        Try
             Dim row As System.Data.DataRowView = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView) 

            Dim pageID As Literal = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("PageID"), Literal)

             If Convert.ToInt32(row("PageID")) = Business.Objects.Constants.A Then
            pageID.Text = "Dummy A"
              End If
             If Convert.ToInt32(row("PageID")) = Business.Objects.Constants.B Then
            pageID.Text = "Dummy B"
               End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            AddErrInfo(ex)
            ErrHandler(ex)
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve, and, indeed, what is the question?

Comment: @fly-i am getting this eror while page loading Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies to type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection'.I need to get the row("PageID") for that i declare  the -row As System.Data.DataRowView but that cause error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing Classic ADO.NET and Entity Framework objects. These are two different worlds and are not automatically interexchangable.

An EF object is a strongly typed object, I suggest that you cast e.Item.DataItem to your EF type instead. From your exception message I suspect that the EF type is named AutoPublishLog.

Try to cast it to this instead:

```
Dim row AS AutoPublishLog = DirectCast(e.Item.DataItem, AutoPublishLog)

'your code

If row.PageID = Business.Objects.Constants.A then
'your code
```

This should work (maybe you need some namespace or other name for AutoPublishLog, but it's hard to tell without knowing your model).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to VB.Net, but I think your `e.Item.DataItem` is not convertible to the type you want... which I doubt. Try to review the types.